# SLURM: Elapsed time does not return day?

Tags: slurm, sacct

Following link https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacct.html defines Elapsed time as follows:

> Elapsed The jobs elapsed time. The format of this fields output is as
>   follows: [DD-[HH:]]MM:SS

Following code returns:

```
jobId = 1;
sacct -j $jobId --format="Elapsed" | tail -n1 | head -n1
```

**Output:** 00:10:11

I won't able to geth the day(DD), which should be 00 on this example. I was hoping to get an output like this: `00:00:10:11`.

[Q] What should I do to see also the used day on Elapsed time output? or day does not exist and hour keep increment after, it covered 24 hours.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the days will only be displayed for jobs that have been running for more than 24 hours.

On our cluster here, I have two jobs, one of which have been running for just over 24 hours (id 319) and one that has been running for just a few minutes (336):

```
$ sacct -j 319 --format="Elapsed" | tail -n1 | head -n1
1-00:26:08
$ sacct -j 336 --format="Elapsed" | tail -n1 | head -n1
  00:08:39
$
```

This has been tested on SLURM version 17.02.2